# remove css bounding box outline

Tags: jquery, css

is there a way to remove the outline of the link when the user clicks the link. Is this a css issue or a jquery

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Click Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

My code creates tabs and which works except when the user clicks the tab I get a bounding box of the outline of the link

Comment: try `<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"> Click Me </a> </li>`

Comment: It's because the item has "Focus". I believe most browsers treat it differently, and it's not a standard CSS feature. So you may have to do several things if it's really important, such is losing focus after clicked, void as stated above, etc., etc.

Comment: @KDM: Are you using the `outline` property or do you have a border around the links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS issue related to the "outline" attribute:

```
<style type="text/css">
   a{ outline: 0 none; }
</style>
```

If you just want to remove the outline on click:

```
<style type="text/css">
   a:focus, a:active{ outline: 0 none; }
</style>
```

Comment: Didn't OP ask to remove the outline when the link is clicked?

Comment: Title of OP is: "remove css bounding box outline".  I do agree that his statement could be interpreted as "only remove it when clicked", but in my experience with working with jQuery tabs, you don't want an outline at all since the containing div is actually defining the UI "look and feel" of the tab itself.

Answer (score 4):

it can be done with css, not widely supported though using `outline:none`

try

```
 li a:focus{ 
   outline:none
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work reliably. Do you have an example of a fiddle?

Comment: @JamesJohnson, what do you mean dosn't seem to work reliably?, and an example could be using FF3 and use the snippet the OP posted and the above CSS i posted.

Comment: Yea, I tried that and it looked funky. Are you sure OP is using `outline`?

Comment: @JamesJohnson, Sorry i don't know if the OP is using the outline property, what do you mean?

Comment: *Sometimes* the outline is removed when you click on it, but as soon as it loses focus the outline returns. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kM9Wz/1/

Comment: @JamesJohnson, yes in this case as expected, it dose because when the element loses focus the default property is applied.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4992/discussion-between-david-and-james-johnson)